# selectCallback that call's a function to see if a item exists I Shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

We are looking for a solution to hide the add to cart button if the selected product variant is already in cart. As well we like to show a new button that says that the selected product is already in cart.
Does we need a if statement?

**Take a look where that should take place: [shopifystore](http://printnil.com/products/angebotsmappe?variant=1023645719)**

```
<form id="add-item-form" action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants">
<button class="addtocart" type="submit" id="add-to-cart" name="add"> Buy this Product</button>
<button class="btn__disabled"> Product is already in cart</button>
</form>
```

Here is a selectCallback that call's a function to see if a item exists

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var cart = {{ cart | json }};

      // returns true if variant exists in cart
      function inCart(variant) {
          for (var i = 0; i < cart.items.length; i++) {
              if (cart.items[i].variant_id === variant.id) {
                  return true;
              }
          }
          return false;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: what you need is a function that runs after a variant is selected. then use inCart, if true hide .addtocart and show the other and if false the opposite.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you show me how the code look like?